# Which Bengali fonts work perfectly on Tor browser

Tags: fonts, tor

I have been facing issues with Bengali fonts when I want to use these on Tor browser.

1. On Firefox on Windows, when I install a new Bengali font, I can use it with this browser as it recognizes new fonts and shows newly installed font in its dropdown menu.
2. But, on the other hand, unlike the red fox, Tor doesn't recognizes newly installed font (**like SolaimanLipi, SiyamRupali, Kalpurush**).......new font doesn't show up in Tor's language selecting menu.
3. I want to set Tor browser to use a newly installed Bengali font.

As far as I can say, **only 'Verdana Bold'(which is not good looking)** gets worked properly with Tor.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Vrinda. It worked for me. The download link is below.

1. Go to the folder in "Tor Browser>Browser>fonts" paste the font there.
2. Restart the browser.
3. Select the Vrinda font default for Bangla from the browser settings.

Good luck.

source -->https://attamkinblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/12/latest-torbrowser-e-bangla-font-problem-solved/